# You need to use a different package name because "com.Mobile.mytestbuddy" is already

Tags: android, google-play

I am uploading android application on google play but It is showing error as : `You need to use a different package name because "com.Mobile.mytestbuddy" is already used by one of your other applications` There is already one app of version 1.2 in google play and this new app's version is 1.29

- What is the wrong with this ?
- Do I need to change anything or
- Do I need to unpublish old app before uploading this new version app ?

Comment: are you updating your application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.
I was adding new Application that's why I was getting error. I click on the application which I wanted to update and there I found option to upload New APK file, I did it and It has been updated.

Comment: Please mark your own answer as correct (green V) to close the question. Thanks ;)

Comment: Ok mine case is petty wierd i deleted my app and when I ma trying to upload the app its showing the above error. Also I have playservices associated with it which i had published now i am not even able to delete that too...and the app in no longer in the application list still it is saying that package name exist

Answer (score -3):

This problem is arise because you did sign this **apk** with different **debug-keystore**. Check it and then reply i will give some more alternatives.

Comment: This type of speculative help should generally be posted as a comment (you also avoid the risk of downvotes that way)