# "You need to use a different package name" after app was denied

Tags: google-play, release, release-management, google-play-console

First, this looks like a duplicate of a few questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40721712/upload-failed-you-need-to-use-a-different-package-name-because-com-example-is), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492667/google-play-says-you-need-to-use-a-different-package-name-why), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876806/you-need-to-use-a-different-package-name-because-com-mobile-mytestbuddy-is-alr) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372983/you-need-to-use-a-different-package-name-because-com-example-is-restricted)), but is not.

The difference is that there is no app in the app store with the name mine is accused of being a duplicate of because the offending app is my own and was denied from the app store.

I attempted to release an app and it was denied for one reason or another. Now I want to submit an updated version that doesn't break the rules, but I'm told that I need to change the package name because '"com.mycompany.the-package-name-i-would-like-to-use" is already used by one of your other applications.'

Must I change the package name, given that the app with the offending name will never be released?

Is there a way to update the original attempt with a new apk? When I go into the project in the console, it just says "app rejected" at the top and shows me some useless analytics.

And I don't have the option to delete the project from the console. The only ones with the trash icon are the ones I never attempted to release.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question related to a specific application and account at an app store, and we are not that app store's support team. We have no access to your account or the submissions you've made to that store. Contact the off-site vendor directly regarding issues with your account or application.

Comment: @KenWhite I wouldn't say it's off topic, package names are strictly related to the code and he is asking something that can be applied to any app, not his specific one.

Comment: @Daniele: No, it's not. It's related to an app store submission, not code, and we can't investigate or resolve issues related to that store submission. This has been [discussed at Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/62576) many times.

Comment: But I imagine a number of people are running into this problem, not just me, and that an answer would benefit the community. Am I not allowed to ask general questions regarding the release of an app? Where should I go to ask such a question? Who is the "offsite vendor"?

Answer (score 0):

Your package name MUST be unique, your app's name can be whatever you want and you can change it after you release your app (if there is a duplicate of your package name, you can't use it). If you change your package name, you have to upload it as a brand new app, you can't update it to an existing app in your Google console.